# Sqlalchemy is not closing connection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The connection is not closing even after process is done.

For example, this script:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
main_engine = create_engine('mysql://gc-api:gc-api@devel/devel')
cnn = main_engine.connect()
result = cnn.execute("select * from radacct")
print("Do Something")
cnn.close()
cnn.invalidate()
main_engine.dispose()
```

console:

```
λ netstat -nat | grep 3306
TCP    172.19.60.21:63062     172.20.197.53:3306     TIME_WAIT
```

After a while, SO releases connection. Why Sqlalchemy is not closing the connect?

Comment: Not sure as to why it is holding on to the connection but if you want to avoid pooling connections you can configure the engine to use the [NullPool](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html?highlight=nullpool#sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool).

Comment: If I replace line with: main_engine = create_engine('mysql://gc-api:gc-api@devel/devel', poolclass=NullPool), I get the same behavior

Comment: This is due to the way TCP/IP works - http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html